# SQL statement used in C# program wont recognize database "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Showing Invalid object name 'CDA'."

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am developing a basic C# application that will read folder names and insert them into a DB.

However it keeps throwing

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name
>   'CDA'.

(CDA is name of my database)

This is the code in question

```
 static void InsertSql(Guid folderGuid, string folderName)
        {
            try
            {
                // Build connection string
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    DataSource = "WIN10-LAP-HJP",
                    UserID = "sa",
                    Password = "Mypassword123",
                    InitialCatalog = "master"
                };

                // Connect to SQL
                Console.Write("Connecting to SQL Server ... ");
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
                    string query = "INSERT INTO CDA ( FolderName) VALUES (@FolderName )";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add("@FolderID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = folderGuid;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@FolderName", SqlDbType.NVarChar ).Value = folderName;



                        connection.Open();
                        var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        // Check Error
                        if (result < 0)
                            Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into Database!");
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

This is an image of my mssql

[image: This is an image of my mssql. SO the database does exist]

My database connection string seems to work

as I do get

```
connecting to sql server...Done
```

And then it throws the error.

Comment: Judging by your screenshot, `CDA` is a _database_, not a _table_

Comment: Of course lol that was a rookie move on my behalf. How would I update this so that it updates into CDA and the into folderinfo?

Comment: Instead of `INSERT INTO CDA`, use something along the lines of `INSERT INTO [CDA].[dbo].[FolderInfo]` (assuming the `FolderInfo` is in the `dbo` schema)

Comment: from cross-database? use `CDA.dbo.folderinfo` instead of just `CDA` (replace `dbo` with the actual schema if necessary)

Comment: @coderStew, change the initial catalog in your connection string to CDA and specify `folderinfo` in the `INSERT` statement if you want to insert into that table.

Comment: I really really **really** hope that your connection string is an example and that you are not using the sa login in your application?

Comment: Insert command just needs the table name.  The database name is optional.  You can put the database name CDA in the connection string as the default database so you do not need to include in the Command Test.  I like put the default name into the connection string so if you change the database name you only have to change the connection string instead of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the name of your database in the SqlConnectionStringBuilder from `master` to `CDA`:

```
InitialCatalog = "CDA"
```

Change your insert statement so that it reflects the actual table where you want to save your data:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.MyTableTableNameGoesHere ( FolderName) VALUES (@FolderName )";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting the entire database and does not specify which table in the database it should use. When considering the information you provided.

Answer (score 1):

As you said CDA is the database name so the below code should be changed with the table name.

```
INSERT INTO CDA (FolderName) VALUES (@FolderName) //Change CDA to table name.
```

It should be

```
INSERT INTO [CDA].[dbo].[FolderInfo] VALUES (@FolderName)
```

Apart from the above two correction you need to change the connection string.

```
InitialCatalog = "master"
```

should be

```
InitialCatalog = "CDA"
```